# Faithful representations of a non-abelian group of order $p^3$

Tags: representation-theory, irreducible-representation

**Question:**

Let $G$ be a non-abelian group of order $p^3$ ($p$ is a prime).

(a) Determine the number of irreducible complex representations of $G$, and find their dimensions.

(b) Which of the irreducible complex representations of $G$ are faithful?

**Answer:**

In part (a), by using class equation, I showed that there are exactly $p^2+p-1$ many irreducible representations. Then using abelianization, I managed to show that there are $p^2$-many $1$-dimensional representations and $p-1$-many $p$-dimensional representations.

However, in the part $(b)$, I couldn't relate those findings above with a representation being faithful. Any help/hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hint 1: What are the finite subgroups of $\mathbb{C}^\times$?

Comment: Hint 2: If a representation $\varphi: G \to \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ has a nontrivial kernel, then $\varphi$ factors through some quotient of $G$ of order dividing $p^2$. What do you know about such groups and their irreps?

Comment: For the hint1, we know that finite subgroups of a multiplicative group of a field are cyclic. Hence, if the representation is $1$-dimensional and kernel is trivial, $G$ must be isomorphic to some cyclic group, which is not the case. Thus, $1$-dimensional representations are not faithful.

Comment: For the hint2, if $ker\varphi\neq1$, then $G/ker\varphi$ is abelian. And irreducible representations of abelian groups are $1$-dimensional. But I cannot see how will I use this knowledge?